# Why is the infinite intersection of open sets not necessarily open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have seen a few questions about this but still don’t understand. Why is it that for infinitely many open sets their intersection might not necessarily be open?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Look at $\bigcap_{n\ge1}(-1/n,1/n)$.

Comment: $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a-1/n,a+1/n)=\{a\}$